# Receiving firebase push on multiply services : sdk and the application which uses it

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing an sdk which uses firebase (every app that uses the sdk is subscribing to firebase and has the `google-services.json` in its context, and when i send a push from my server to `EventsService` listed below, i receive the push in [onMessageRecieved](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onMessageReceived(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage)).

AppManifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.sampleapplication">

    ...

    <application
       ...

        <service android:name=".EventsService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EventsService.java :

```
public class EventsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        ...
    }

}
```

SdkManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.sdk">

    ...

    <application
       ...

        <service android:name=".SdkEventsService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now, i want `SdkEventsService` to receive the event as well, and basically catch the event in the sdk as well.
However, `SdkEventsService` receives the push from firebase **ONLY** if the `EventsService` defined in the app is deleted.

**Fyi, it seems that the issue is really : how to define 2 services that catch `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` simultaneously and are kinda independant of each other.**

1. I tried setting `SdkEventsService` a lot of tags (`android:exported="true"` fe), but none worked.
2. I don't want `EventsService` to 'alert' the sdk when a push is received, because i don't want to rely on the client to notify the sdk.
3. I don't want `EventsService` to extend a base class from the sdk, which will receive the push, because well.. it's quite ugly and not professional.
4. Basically, i would like a minimum client interference, and i wish the process to be transparent as much as possible.

just saying : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38596093/5130239) is really not my issue, and i haven't find anything like this here :(

Comment: Your problem is due to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606179/2910520. One option is to launch the SdkEventsService from the EventsService and sincerely i dont know why you shouldn't "rely on the client to notify the sdk" because is the same thing than relying on the Push notification system and your EventsService

Comment: :( i don't want to relay of the developers to call a method when they receive a push. what if a developer 'forgets' to do so ?

Comment: Sincerely i'm not understanding what you are building, If a library or a framework or something similar and if this choice is the only available for your use case. But beside this, if you write a good documentation you will eliminate 95% of implementation problems by developers.

Comment: exatly... not 100% ...

Comment: Left 5% is distraction or lazyness of developers and there is no way to reduce this number to 0, even if you check the Google documentation or every library produced in the world, you have no chance to prevent some developers to create issues in forum or github only because they didn't read all the documentation :D