# Valid name for Android Package Name

Tags: android, package-name

If I own a domain name like e.g Dan-Carlos.com

Does the andoid package name allow use like com.dan-carlos.com?

I have not tried using it but I am curious if anyone tried domain name with hyphen '-' in it.

Comment: Good answer on package naming conventions followed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/392271

Answer (score 16, accepted):

refer to my working years and some web pages like [this](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/09/hyphen-ussage-in-package-names.html)
 you should replace "-" dashes with "_" underline.

if web site is : dan-carlos.com

package name is : com.dan_carlos

Comment: I just experimented and package name --> package com.dan_carlos.pname worked. THANKS a lot.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**docs**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) :

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters.

So, sadly you can't use anything else except for English letters, digits, the character "." and the character "_" .

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately the hyphen '-' is not acceptable in a package name.

You can simply test this out by right clicking a project and going to properties -> Android -> rename application package and try out what is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Allowed characters in package name are A to Z (small and caps case), period (.) and underscore ( _ ). So you can have package name com.dan.carlos or com.dan_carlos