# error when uploading apk file to the markt

Tags: android, apk

I have the following error when trying to upload a new apk version of my android app ? any idea please:

The package name of your apk (Psychoanalysis.Quiz) is invalid. Package names must start with a character and can only contain characters, numbers, underscores and dots. They must have at least one dot, cannot end with a dot, and cannot contain any runs of more than one consecutive dot.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/586859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the new design.

The button is in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, package names reflect your reversed domain name, such as: com.mydomain.psychquiz. This is to keep them globally unique. That said, a package name should start with a lower-case letter.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is more info.

Comment: but I have upgraded it many times before, it was accepted before, what should I do now , should I change the name and upload it as a new app?

Comment: It's odd that it ever worked. Contact google and ask them what to do. If they fixed their bug of previously allowing incorrect package names, they should have a plan in place to allow an upgrade path for those affected.