# Android - Package name com.myappname or com.myappname.myappname?

Tags: android

I'm creating new Android project and since I don't have a domain, should I name my package com.myappname or com.myappname.myappname?

Comment: you can give a package name which you want.....any

Comment: you could refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/1554935

Comment: Peoples sometimes are so stupid...

Comment: Also keep in mind that com.myappname.myappname will be better if you are planing  for making more than one app... it can be a standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name is used for unique identification for your application.

You can give  `com.myappname` or `com.myappname.myappname`

Only thing is that it must not conflict with any existing application in Play Store

**The difference  is that**

if you give `com.myappname` you will be mapped internally as  **`com/myappname`**

and

if you give `com.myappname.myappname` you will be mapped internally as  **`com/myappname/myappname`**

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter, but the convention is to use reverse domain name format

com.domain.appname

Answer (score 0):

It is convention to use  your package name as a domain name for marking unique.
You can use any package name as you wish. like com.projectname

Answer (score 0):

Your Package Name will be your app identity on Play Store, Choose whichever Suits your app.

Generally com.example.example is used, You can use com.example or com.example.example.example , But it should be available on play store, If you are not making apps for `playstore` then thee is no restriction for your Package name.
For better idea about Naming Conventions , [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention/6273935#6273935)