# Android can i use in.myapp.app1 as package name instead of com.myapp.app1? because in domains are much cheaper than com domains?

Tags: android, package

Please help me out.I have searched so many forums but nowhere found any solution.I have gone through this link also.
[Android - Package Name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention)

Comment: You don't need to own the domain although you should use a unique name which is not already used.  com.google.* would be a bad choice for example.

Comment: @Simon oh..Super.I thought every app that goes to gPLAY should have one dedicated site.Thanx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure what are you asking... Yes you can use whatever package name you want. When you create the new project modify the package name field. Like this:

[image]

But when will you pay for the "domain"?? I am not understanding you...

Comment: Although nothing forces you technically and yes, you can type anything into that field, package names *do* follow a very clear convention: the domain you own, written out in reverse. So, if you own *www.somedomain.com,* you use `com.somedomain.XXX`. If your domain name is *www.somedomain.me,* you use `me.somedomain.XXX`. If you don't have a domain name, you should still adhere to this convention to make sure there will be no collisions out there in the wild, maybe to reuse another unique net identifier like parts of an e-mail address, of a github repository or similar.