# Validate package name, application name and version name in Android

Tags: android, validation

We have validation methods for email address, name, zip code etc.

Is there something similar for Package Name, Application Name and Version Name used in Android apps? Is there any documentation for the same, like what valid characters are allowed?

I see that version code for all apps is always integer.

Answer (score 0):

**Package Name:** 
This is already answered here: [Android - Package Name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention).

**App Name:** 
A short app name for display on the device menu should be maximum of 12 character (including spaces) and a longer name for the App Store or Android Market should be maximum of 30 character (including spaces).

**Version code:** 
It can be any *integer* value. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. Check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#vcode

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But it is not perfect validation. For package name it is just a convention (which may or may not be followed). I want to know allowed characters in each field. Thank you for your effort.