# In React Native, how to use sub package name for Android, like com.foo.bar?

Tags: android, react-native, package-name

I would like to change my React Native android app package name to something like `com.foo.bar` but it only allows for `com.foo` and things are broken when I change.

Is there a proper way to change it to use sub package name?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention

Comment: @ChrisGeirman No. I already know how to change in native android, but looks like react-native has issues with second period.

Comment: I have the same problem... Why is there no easy way to find the answer to this especially in deployment.