# public class ParcelableGeofence has disappeared from play-services:10.0.1. Is there a workaround?

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

Upgrading play-services from 9.6.1 to 10.0.1, public class `ParcelableGeofence` seems to have disappeared (package `com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence` has gone).

Is there any replacement method or workaround in order to get Latitude and Longitude from a Geofence?

i.e. as a replacement for this...

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence;



Geofence g;
ParcelableGeofence p = (ParcelableGeofence) g;
p.getLatitude(); p.getLongitude();
```

And as a supplementary question, is it necessary to upgrade the `play-services` I'm using? Am I getting hung up on this issue? Should I just carry on using 9.6.1  (i.e. if it ain't broke, why fix it!)

Comment: I don't see in this [Release Note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) regarding `ParcelableGeofence` in 10.0.1. However, you're right. I don't also see any documentations regarding `ParcelableGeofence`. I found this [sample](https://github.com/vhoen/Android-Geofence-21) that explains how to use Geofence. For yout additional question, yes it is necessary to provide new functionality to existing apps. Just make sure that you changed all the versions to 10.0.1 in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: @abielita Thanks for your comment. I had read the release note and wondered why it wasn't mentioned. My conclusion was that as the package was named "internal" then perhaps I shouldn't have been using it in the first place? Do you know whether there is a Google forum for play-services where I can perhaps ask?

Comment: For the package name, you may refer with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention) for the guideline/standard to name the package. For the Google Forum, you may try [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/play).