# Android Package Name equals my URL?

Tags: android, google-play

so in order to make package names unique we should use reversed urls. so example.com would be com.example.myapp - now, if my TLD is .DE (germany) and not .COM, should (must?) I use de.example.myapp ? It would kinda make sense, but I'm not sure how the google play store will react, maybe a .COM TLD is a must?

Comment: Nope, `.com` is not must

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be longer as much as you want. Shorter as short you think. But primary condition is that package name is unique.

You can use any name. More detail read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/2900893)

Answer (score 1):

The package name does not matter one bit. Hell, you could even name it

```
com.google.seriously
```

You absolutely do NOT need to have any website associated with the app, and many app developers might not have a website to begin with. The reason people name the packages as backward urls is really just for traditions sake. Also, if everybody started just naming things willy nilly, then there would be 1000 packages called `camera` and `map` in the play store. Since domain names are unique, this practice of backward urls just helps to distinguish packages. But nobody is actually going to check if my app was produced by google.com in the above example...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the this package de.example.myapp 
see here is a live example that is using different package

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**io.wifimap.wifimap**