# Appropriate with personal name as package name when no domain? (Google Play)

Tags: android, package-name

Having researched some Android package naming conventions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention/6273935#6273935) post, I learned that package names based on domains is the most common, and if one doesn't own a domain one can e.g. make a package name based on one's email address.

Now, I don't own a domain, and I'm not ready to buy one. However, I do find the email-address package names to be quite inelegant/amateurish. Would `firstnamesurname.applicationname` instead be an appropriate package name for an app to be published in Google Play?

Comment: Are you going to publish your App in Google Play ?

Comment: Yes - I will update original post

Comment: Well, then I guess you have many more choices than to use a mail accout with the following format `<top_level_domain>.<mail_domain>.<mail_user>.<project_name>`.

Comment: Just, rename you package as you would name you future domain.

Comment: @Hector What if he is not planning on getting any ?

Comment: Then nothing will happens. The package is just an ID for you code.