# how to set a package name without Website?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, package-name

I've recently started creating an app for Android. but i do not have a Website. 
 how to get Package name. Can i make it `com.example.(app name)` ?
and how to know if it is available or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

package name have no concern with any website. It is used to identify your application uniquely in your mobile phone and in any App store. You can set any name or string in your package name i.e **com.example.myfirstapplication** 
it is not necessary that there should be com.example in the package name you can change them also i.e **my.first.application.packagename**

Answer (score 2):

You can set whatever package name you like, as long as it isnt already taken when you publish it on the playstore.

More good reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/5644761