# App package name having different domain than the website domain

Tags: android, ios, package, mobile-website, publishing

I created an Android and iOS app with this kind of package name:

```
com.myapp.app
```

As you can see it is not in the form

```
com.mycompany.myapp
```

I do not own the com domain, but instead I do own a different domain (with a working website), let's say

```
www.myapp.abcd
```

I am not confortable with this, because I read that the app package should have the reverse of the domain as the prefix. I used the com domain for the package as it is a common practice, it is a very standard form.

I do not think every developer owns the com domain of the package, be it including the company name or the app name.

I have more than one version of the app, with different set of features, and some versions are published, some are going to be published, on the Android and iOS platforms but possibly also on other platforms.

I could change the package name for the upcoming versions, and/or even unpublish/recreate the original ones, at least some of them.

More difficult is to grab the com domain because now it is very expensive.

So I would like to know:

-is it dangerous that my app has a package name that has the com prefix, when someone could in principle create a website with that extension because it purchases the com domain?

-if I change the package prefix, is it advisable or sensible to have the abcd.myapp.app form?

Answer (score 2):

The application ID / package name doesn't matter. You can leave it as it is. It is merely a convention to prevent name collision if e.g. you publish a library with a package name that collides with another package name.

See this question and answers for reference: [Android - Package Name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention)