# Why in android manifest permissions have different constant values "path"?

Tags: android, kotlin

I noticed that some permissions have a constant value:

```
com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

while others:

```
android.permission.STATUS_BAR
```

or

```
com.google.launcher3.permission.READ_SETTING.
```

Why there is this difference beetween "com.android.","android.permission." and "com.google."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions can be defined as any arbitrary String, but they're supposed to be unique. Library authors can define their own, and you can even define *your* own for your own apps. The convention is to use a String with a prefix that follows the [same conventions as for package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention), to keep it from conflicting with anyone else's.

The permissions in Android have various names because they are defined by and related to different subsystems of the OS.