# Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-studio, google-play-console

i am getting this error while uploading application on google playstore for testing

**"Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: myApp.crashlyticsinitprovider, myApp.firebaseinitprovider, myApp.lifecycle-trojan."**

Here is my build.gradle (App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def sdkVersion = 33,
    toolsVersion = sdkVersion.toString(),
    minimumSdkSupported = 14,
    internalVersionNumber = 15,
    externalVersionNumber = "1.2.7"

android {
    compileSdkVersion sdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion toolsVersion
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myAPP"
        archivesBaseName = "myAPP"
        dimension "my"
        minSdkVersion minimumSdkSupported
        targetSdkVersion sdkVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode internalVersionNumber
        versionName externalVersionNumber
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

def dependencyVersions = [
        // production
        supportLibrary      : "$sdkVersion.0.0",
        jackson             : "2.5.3",
        constraintLayout    : "1.1.3",
        coroutines          : '1.1.1',
        androidArchLifecycle: "1.1.1",
        firebaseCore        : "16.0.7",
        firebaseMessaging   : "17.4.0",
        crashlytics         : "2.9.9",
        dagger              : "2.13",
        // testing
        mockk               : "1.9",
        jUnit               : "1.1.0",
        testRunner          : "1.1.1",
        espresso            : "3.1.1"
]

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$dependencyVersions.jackson"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$dependencyVersions.coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$dependencyVersions.coroutines"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$dependencyVersions.constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dependencyVersions.dagger"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dependencyVersions.dagger"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$dependencyVersions.androidArchLifecycle"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$dependencyVersions.androidArchLifecycle"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$dependencyVersions.firebaseCore"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$dependencyVersions.firebaseMessaging"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$dependencyVersions.crashlytics"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-common:$dependencyVersions.mockk"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$dependencyVersions.mockk"
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$dependencyVersions.jUnit"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$dependencyVersions.coroutines"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$dependencyVersions.espresso"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$dependencyVersions.espresso"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$dependencyVersions.espresso"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$dependencyVersions.jUnit"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$dependencyVersions.testRunner"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$dependencyVersions.testRunner"

    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}

apply from: '../quality/ktlint.gradle'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/rijksoverheid_blue" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.MainViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.LoginViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.RegisterViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.RegisterInfoViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.RequestsViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="IDT Aanvragen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.SubmitRequestViewController"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="Nieuwe aanvraag"
            android:parentActivityName=".controller.RequestsViewController"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".controller.RequestsViewController" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".controller.DialogActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog" />

        <service android:name=".features.notification.IDTFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Error seems pretty clear. What have you already tried to solve it?

Comment: @jorn i wasn't clear about error can you help

Comment: I am also facing same issue with PACKAGENAME.AudienceNetworkContentProvider, PACKAGENAME.FacebookInitProvider, PACKAGENAME.firebaseinitprovider, PACKAGENAME.mobileadsinitprovider. 

someone please suggest some solution. 
Playstore is getting more complex day by day.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your package name as per convention. You can check full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273935/1318946).

It should be like:

- **com.yourdomain.app**

I believe the one word will be rejected by Playstore. I know the error appears strange, but I just had the same problem and solved it by changing the package name because the old package was already on Playstore.

Comment: I have checked package name..but it is not used & available to use. still facing such issue while trying to add new bundle file for Internal Testing.

Answer (score -3):

Folks ,

- The issue is major for Play Store policy. But the solution is simple.
- **You are trying to use the same name of the package to upload your app on the Play Store.  Just change your package name and try again.**
- The case is generated also if your app is in the draft in another play console .

[Connect with me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/hardik-chitroda-768873139/)